# Variance of sum of random vectors - a proof

Tags: variance, random-variable, multivariate-distribution, vector-fields

For nonrandom matrices $A(rXk)$,$ B(rXm)$, and $c(rX1)$, how does one show that 
$$\newcommand{\Var}{{\rm Var}}\newcommand{\Cov}{{\rm Cov}}\newcommand{\*}{{\times}}  
\Var(AX+BY+c)=A\Var(X)A′+ B \Var(Y) B′+ A \Cov(X,Y)B′+ B\Cov(Y,X)A′
$$

I have started it like this:
Let 
\begin{align}
      Z &= AX + BY + c  \\
   E(Z) &= A\*E(X) + B\*E(Y) + c  \\
 Z-E(Z) &= A(X-E(X)) + B(Y-E(Y))  \\  \\
\Var(Z) &= E\Big[\big(Z-E(Z)\big)\big(Z-E(Z)\big)′ \Big]   \\
        &= E{\Big[A\big(X-E(X)\big) + B\big(Y-E(Y)\big)\Big]\Big[A\big(X-E(X)\big) + B\big(Y-E(Y)\big)\Big]′ }
\end{align}
Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1):

Is it self-study question? I do not know where is your start point.

Suppose you know that

$$Var(AY) = AVar(Y)A'$$
Then $Var(Z) = Var(AX + BY) = Var((A, B)(X', Y')') =(A, B)(Var ((X',Y')')(A, B)'$
Then writing $Var ((X',Y')')$ as a 2x2 block matrix, and following the basic matrix operators, you get the result.

Comment: Well the question is not clear on what the start point is but I suppose you could assume that Var(AY) = AVar(Y)A' as that is also easy to prove